# 'Biggest date before' on a WHERE clause (OleDB SELECT method)

Tags: vba, ms-access, oledb, where-clause

I'm importing data from an `Access DB file` to `Excel` using `VBA` and I'm struggling with a `WHERE` clause on one of my queries. This is not so much a technical difficulty. It is more like a *strategy* difficulty.

Right now, after establish the connection,

```
Dim prv As String: prv = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                         "Data Source=..." & _
                         "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=..."
Dim DBcon As New Connection
DBcon.Open prv
```

I use the next query:

```
Dim BDrcs As New Recordset
RC01.Open "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE Field1=Dateserial(2020,5,26)", DBcon
```

For the purposes this is intended, the code is working fine! However, my goal is to get `Table1` values `WHERE Field1` is the greater date before `2020/05/26` case there's **not** any entries with the date `2020/05/26`.

Is it possible to do this on one single query?

Please don't bother to reply an alternative method (not that I don't want it, is just not necessary). I know I could always previously get all the data from the table (or, at least, all the data before `2020/05/26`), check for the greater date and then get the data again. I'm simply trying to get the data with just one query, if it's possible at all...

Comment: Maybe `SELECT a.* from Table1 a WHERE a.Field1 = (select Max(b.Field1) from Table1 b where b.Field1 <= Dateserial(2020,5,26))`

Comment: Nice approach... :) I'll give it a try tomorrow at work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `Max` doesn't work, you could try a sub query using `TOP`. Something like:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 AS A 
WHERE A.Field1=
    (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 B.Field1 FROM Table1 AS B 
    WHERE B.Field1<=DateSerial(2020,5,26) 
    ORDER BY B.Field1 DESC)
```

Regards,